# PyQGIS script crashes QGIS 3 when removing a custom pluginLayer which has custom legend

Tags: pyqgis-3

I upgrade a 2.18 plugin to 3.4.

PluginLayer has been refactored and I could not create a custom legend as simple as previous major version of QGIS 2 :

> QgsDefaultPluginLayerLegend was removed. Use QgsMapLayer::setLegend()
> to provide legend nodes for plugin layers.
> as it's written here https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

I followed steps :

- create my custom pluginlayer
- add to mapLayer

```py
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
legend = layer.makeLegend()
layer.setLegend(legend)
```

Here is my pluginLayer class :

```py
class PSudLayer(QgsPluginLayer):

def __init__(self,session, type, name):
    QgsPluginLayer.__init__(self, type, name)
    self.layerType = type
    self.session=session
    self.conf = None
    self.transparency = 0
    self.setValid(True)

def makeLegend(self):
    return PSudLegend(self.session,self.conf['uuid'])
```

and here my custom legend

```py
class PSudLegend(QgsMapLayerLegend):


    def __init__(self, session, uuid):
        QgsMapLayerLegend.__init__(self)
        self.nodes = []
        url = session.baseUrl+'/geocat/legend/'+uuid
        r = session.get(url)
        self.legends = json.loads(r.readAll().data().decode())
        self.globalcount = 0
        self.countBoucle = 0
        self.countRecursive = 0
        self.icon = QIcon()

    def recursiveLoad(self,legends, nodeLayer):
        self.countRecursive +=1
        self.countBoucle = 0
        size = legends['children'].__len__()
        for child in legends['children']:
            if 'children' in child:
                self.recursiveLoad(child, nodeLayer)
            else:
                if size > self.nodes.__len__(): # hack car la boucle passe plus d'une fois ....
                    image = QPixmap()
                    iStr= child["icon"].split(",")[1]
                    i64 = base64.b64encode(iStr.encode()) # hack parsing error (multiple de 4)
                    image.loadFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(base64.b64decode(i64)))
                    self.icon = QIcon(image)
                    node = QgsSimpleLegendNode(nodeLayer,child['title'],self.icon)
                    self.nodes.append(node)

    def createLayerTreeModelLegendNodes(self, nodeLayer):
        if 'children' in self.legends:
            self.recursiveLoad(self.legends, nodeLayer)

        return self.nodes

    def removeLegend(self):
        for node in  self.nodes:
            node = None
        self.nodes = None
        self.icon =None
        return True
```

All works fine as I remove the layer from the `treeLayerPanel`.  QGIS simply crashes.

I tried to remove nodes in my legend with no success and call it when `removeLayer` is called.

`QgsProject.instance().layerWillBeRemoved.connect(self.PSudData.removeLayer)`

```py
def removeLayer(self,layerid):

    for layer in self.parent.service_layers:
        if layer.id() == layerid:
            layer.legend.removeLegend()
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
```

I get a typeError when I tried the filtering option of the layerTree.
`PSudLegend.createLayerTreeModelLegendNodes(), index 0 has type 'QgsSimpleLegendNode' but 'QgsLayerTreeModelLegendNode' is expected`
Which I don't understand because QgsLayerTreeModelLegendNode is an abstract class and QgsSimpleLegendNode extends from QgsLayerTreeModelLegendNode.

When I tried to `refreshLayerLegend()` from the `LayerTreeModel` and I also get the same TypeError.

Very confused.

Comment: just to figure out : if I don't set the legend to the layer with  `layer.setLegend(legend)` QGIS does not crash when I remove the layer.

Comment: If you delete this line `layer.legend.removeLegend()` , it also crashes?

Comment: I had comment  `            QgsProject.instance().layerWillBeRemoved.connect(self.PSudData.removeLayer) ` and Qgis still crash

Comment: the crash come up  before/during the "layerWillBeRemoved" event of the QgsProject and also on the "willBeDeleted" event of the QgsMapLayer Object

Comment: this also happen when I move by drag and drop a layer in the treeLayer

Comment: If you debug the code where QGIS dies?, it can help you a little more. You could also prepare an example so that the people can reproduce it better

Comment: the last place I can stop QGIS befor it died is an Qevent :  "ChildRemoved". The crash come up also with any action which need refreshing the legend layer. I could have a python TypeError : `PSudLegend.createLayerTreeModelLegendNodes(), index 0 has type 'QgsSimpleLegendNode' but 'QgsLayerTreeModelLegendNode' is expected`

Comment: You can look at this example in case it can help you https://github.com/BRGM/gml_application_schema_toolbox/blob/474df9894000132c757e1f15a2daabbac902e699/gml_application_schema_toolbox/core/load_gmlas_in_qgis.py#L62